In jest, how do you mock a named export from an ES6 module?
It seems like I was able to get this to work before, but now I can't find my old code. I've been looking at this question for help, but so far I can't get the mock to work.
I have this ES6 module:
export default "default"

export const getCatFact = () => ({fact: "cats are quadrupeds"}); 

Which is used by this test component:
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { getCatFact } from "./CatService";

const Component = () => {
  
  const {fact} = getCatFact(); 
    return <div data-testid="my-div">{fact}</div>
}

export default Component;

If I try to mock like this...like Andy's accepted answer:

import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import Component from "./Component";


test("mock an es6 module", async () => {
    const mockCatFact = jest.fn();

    mockCatFact.mockImplementation(() => ({fact: "mocked"}));
    
    
    jest.mock('./CatService', () => ({
        __esModule: true, 
        default: "mockedDefaultExport",
        getCatFact: mockCatFact
      }));
    
    
    render(
        <Component />
    );
    
    const myDiv = await screen.findByTestId("my-div")
    expect(myDiv).toHaveTextContent("mocked");//Fails! value not mocked
});

And I've tried it in a way similar to falsarella's answer:
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import Component from "./Component";
import { getCatFact } from "./CatService";


test("mock an es6 module", async () => {
   getCatFact.mockImplementation(() => ({fact: "mocked"}));
    // get me "TypeError: _CatService.getCatFact.mockImplementation is not a function"
    
    render(
        <Component />
    );
    
    const myDiv = await screen.findByTestId("my-div")
    expect(myDiv).toHaveTextContent("mocked");//Fails! value not mocked
});

But in both cases, the unmocked value is what I get. The code is available in this repo.  Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

It turns out you don't have to write a factory function that returns the mocked module with a __esModule: true, anymore. Or if it's possible to do so, I'm doing it wrong.
This article shows a simpler way.   You can import * as someModuleAlias from "./myModule" and then mock the named exported function with someModuleAlias.myFxn = jest.fn(() => //mock implementation here.   For example:
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import * as useCatSvcHook from './CatService';
import Component from "./Component";


test("mock an es6 module", async () => {
    useCatSvcHook.getCatFact = jest.fn(() => ({fact: "mocked"}))
    
    render(
        <Component />
    );
    
    const myDiv = await screen.findByTestId("my-div")
    expect(myDiv).toHaveTextContent("mocked");
});

and you can also spyOn the module:
test("spyOn an es6 module", async () => {
    const mockHook = jest.spyOn(useCatSvcHook, 'getCatFact');
    mockHook.mockImplementation(() => ({ fact: "mocked" }));

    render(
        <Component />
    );

    const myDiv = await screen.findByTestId("my-div")
    expect(myDiv).toHaveTextContent("mocked"); // works! 
});

...which lets you restore the original module behavior with mockHook.mockRestore() - to name one way of doing it.  I've updated my repo in hopes that it helps somebody.
